# Editar lista de objetos com POST do form em MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Tenho as duas classes abaixo. Eu sei fazer uma tela para inserir os dados, e pegar os dados de PESSOA e TELEFONE, por `model` e por `List`.

Mas como fazer isto em uma tela de edição? Quero mostrar os dados da `PESSOA` e a lista de `TELEFONE`, mas como faço para recuperar os itens de `TELEFONE` com os respectivos ID, para editar os valores.

Mostrar na tela eu sei, fazendo um `foreach`, e criando os respectivos TextFor, porém como recuperar isto em um `POST`de FORM.

```
public class PESSOA
{
  public int PessoaID { get; set; }
  public string Nome { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Telefone> Telefones { get; set; }
}

public class TELEFONE
{
  public int TelefoneID { get; set; }
  public int PessoaID { get; set; }
  public string Numero { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minha solução requer que você instale o [Package NuGet BeginCollectionItem HtmlHelper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/).

### Controller

Lógica necessária para edição apenas no Entity Framework 5. No 6 não precisa.

Para criação de uma pessoa, essa lógica pode ser simplificada.

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    // Entradas Excluídas
    if (pessoa.Telefones == null)
    {
        foreach (var telefoneExcluido = context.Telefones.Single(t => t.TelefoneId == phone.CustomerPhoneID);
        context.Telefones.Remove(telefoneExcluido);
        context.SaveChanges();
    } else {
        // Registros Antigos
        foreach (var telefone in context.Telefones.AsNoTracking().Where(t => t.PessoaId == pessoa.PessoaId).ToList())
        {
            if (pessoa.Telefones.Any(t => t.TelefoneId == telefone.TelefoneId))
            {
                var telefoneExcluido = context.Telefones.Single(t => t.TelefoneId == telefone.TelefoneId);
                context.Telefones.Remove(telefoneExcluido);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        // Phones
        if (pessoa.Telefones.Any())
        {
            foreach (var telefone in pessoa.Telefones)
            {
                if (telefone.PessoaId == 0)
                {
                    telefone.Pessoa = pessoa;
                    context.Telefones.Add(telefone);
                } else {
                    context.Entry(telefone).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }

                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }

    context.Entry(pessoa).State = EntityState.Modified;
    context.SaveChanges();

    scope.Complete();
}
```

### View Principal

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Telefones)
    <div class="controls">
        <ul id="PhonesEditor" style="list-style-type: none">
            @if (Model.Teleones != null)
            {
                foreach (var telefone in Model.Telefones)
                {
                    Html.RenderPartial("_CustomerPhonesEditor", telefone);
                }
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
    <p><a id="addAnother" class="small-button">@Language.AddPhone</a></p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#addAnother").click(function () {
        $.get('/Customers/CustomerPhoneRow', function (template) {
            $("#PhonesEditor").append(template);
        });
    });
</script>
```

### _CustomerPhonesEditor.cshtml

```
@model SeuProjeto.Models.Telefone
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Telefones"))
{  
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TelefoneId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PessoaId)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Language.Phone

        <div class="controls">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Numero)
            <script type='text/javascript'>
                $('input[name$="Numero"]').mask("(99) 9999-9999?9");
                $('input[name$="Numero"]').focusout(function () {
                    var phone, element;
                    element = $(this);
                    element.unmask();
                    phone = element.val().replace(/\D/g, '');
                    if (phone.length > 10) {
                        element.mask("(99) 99999-999?9");
                    } else {
                        element.mask("(99) 9999-9999?9");
                    }
                }).trigger('focusout');
            </script>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Telefone)

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <a onclick="$(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();" class="small-button" style="float: left;">@Language.Delete</a>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

### Action Adicional no Controller, para inserir uma Partial por Ajax

```
    public ActionResult LinhaTelefone()
    {
        var telefone = new Telefone();

        return PartialView("_CustomerPhonesEditor", telefone);
    }
```

Comment: Depois de conseguir implementar ao salvar o model dá o erro `Falha na operação: a relação não pôde ser alterada porque uma ou mais propriedades da chave estrangeira não é nula. Quando uma alteração é feita em uma relação, a propriedade relacionada da chave estrangeira é definida como um valor nulo. Se a chave estrangeira não der suporte a valores nulos, uma nova relação deverá ser definida, a propriedade da chave estrangeira deverá ser atribuída a outro valor não nulo ou o objeto não relacionado deverá ser excluído.`

Comment: @marlon.tiedt Pode abrir uma nova pergunta com o seu código até agora?