# Erro ao salvar lista de objetos MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Conforme o post [Editar lista de objetos com POST do form em MVC C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30451/editar-lista-de-objetos-com-post-do-form-em-mvc-c/30457#30457) consegui fazer a minha aplicação mostrar os valores. Porém ao tentar salvar os dados dá o erro:

```
The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.
```

Em português, para documentação:

```
Falha na operação: a relação não pôde ser alterada porque uma ou mais propriedades da chave estrangeira não é nula. Quando uma alteração é feita em uma relação, a propriedade relacionada da chave estrangeira é definida como um valor nulo. Se a chave estrangeira não der suporte a valores nulos, uma nova relação deverá ser definida, a propriedade da chave estrangeira deverá ser atribuída a outro valor não nulo ou o objeto não relacionado deverá ser excluído.
```

A minha implementação é esta:

### Model

```
public class ProdutoPadrao : IEntidadeBase
{
  [Key]
  public int ProdutoPadraoID { get; set; }
  [Display(Name = "Descrição")]
  public string Descricao { get; set; }
  [Display(Name = "Detalhe")]
  public string Detalhe { get; set; } 
  public virtual ICollection<ProdutoPadraoCaracteristica> ListaProdutoCaracteristica { get; set; }    
}

public class ProdutoPadraoCaracteristica : IEntidadeBase
{
  [Key]
  public int ProdutoPadraoCaracteristicaID { get; set; }
  public int ProdutoPadraoID { get; set; }
  public string Descricao { get; set; }
  public int TipoCaracteristicaID { get; set; }    
  [ForeignKey("ProdutoPadraoID")]
  public virtual ProdutoPadrao ProdutoPadrao { get; set; }
}
```

### Controller GET

```
[ControleDeAcesso(TipoAcao.Normal)]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Detalhar(int id)
{
    using (var db = new ERPContext())
    {
        var produtoPadrao = db.ProdutoPadrao.Include("ListaProdutoCaracteristica").Where(w => w.ProdutoPadraoID == id).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
        var retorno = EntidadeBaseExt.ValidarRegistro(produtoPadrao, TipoAcao.Visualizar);
        if (retorno != "")
        {
            TempData["MsgRetornoError"] = retorno;
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        ViewBag.ListaCaracteristica = new SelectList(ListagemPadrao.ListaTipoCaracteristica(), "Key", "Texto");
        ViewBag.ListaUnidadeMedida = new SelectList(db.UnidadeMedida.ToListERP().Select(l => new ItemLPesquisa { Key = l.UnidadeMedidaID, Texto = l.Descricao }).ToArray(), "Key", "Texto");
        return View(produtoPadrao);
    }
}
```

### Controller POST

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
[ControleDeAcesso(TipoAcao.Normal)]
public ActionResult Detalhar(string btnSubmit, ProdutoPadrao model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {                
        return View(model);
    }

    using (var db = new ERPContext())
    {
        var produtoPadrao = db.ProdutoPadrao.Include("ListaProdutoCaracteristica").Where(w => w.ProdutoPadraoID == model.ProdutoPadraoID).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
        var retorno = FlexGestor.Helpers.EntidadeBaseExt.ValidarRegistro(produtoPadrao, TipoAcao.Gravar);
        if (retorno != "")
        {
            TempData["MsgRetornoError"] = retorno;
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        model.ListaProdutoCaracteristica = null;
        if (btnSubmit != "Excluir")                
            UpdateModel(produtoPadrao);

        FlexGestor.Helpers.EntidadeBaseExt.AtribuirValores(produtoPadrao, btnSubmit);
        db.Entry(produtoPadrao).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        if (btnSubmit == "Excluir")
            return RedirectToAction("Index", controller);

        return RedirectToAction("Detalhar", controller, new { id = model.ProdutoPadraoID });
    }
}
```

### View Principal

```
@model FlexGestor.Models.ProdutoPadrao


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="row">                
        @Html.TituloPagina("Visualizando Produto Padrão", "Clique para abrir a ajuda", "#help_produtoPadrao")
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProdutoPadraoID)
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Descricao) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Descricao)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Descricao, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Detalhe) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Detalhe)
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Detalhe, new { @class = "form-control", @rows = "4" })
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ListaProdutoCaracteristica)
        <div class="controls">
            <ul id="PhonesEditor" style="list-style-type: none">
                @if (Model.ListaProdutoCaracteristica != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in Model.ListaProdutoCaracteristica)
                    {
                        Html.RenderPartial("_CustomerPhonesEditor", item);
                    }
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
        <p><a id="addAnother" class="small-button">AddPhone</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="row">        
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.BotaoTelaDetalhar()
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

### View Detalhe

```
@model FlexGestor.Models.ProdutoPadraoCaracteristica


@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("ListaProdutoCaracteristica"))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProdutoPadraoID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProdutoPadraoCaracteristicaID)

    <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.TipoCaracteristicaID) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.TipoCaracteristicaID)
        @Html.DropDownList("TipoCaracteristicaID", (SelectList)ViewBag.ListaCaracteristica, String.Empty,
                      new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-9">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Descricao) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Descricao)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Descricao, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <a onclick="$(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();" class="small-button" style="float: left;">Delete</a>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Só esclareça uma coisa: em qual linha desses fontes está o erro?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez desculpa, esqueci de dizer...Nesta linha `db.SaveChanges();`

Comment: O que faz esta função? `UpdateModel()`

Comment: Ele pega os dados do `model` e seta os valores no objeto. Se não me engano ou é do .Net ou do Entity Framework.

Comment: Pode por favor colocá-la na pergunta?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez verifiquei e ela é da classe `System.Web.Mvc`. Acho que o problema está pois estou usando MVC 4 e EF 4. Será se eu atualizar pode ser que funciona?

Comment: Não acho que seja isso. Acho que o método `UpdateModel()` altera alguma coisa que não deveria.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez o que eu acho engraçado é se não tiver nada na listagem, ele salva certo. ?Porém se tiver um registro já na `ListaProdutoCaracteristica` da o erro. Vou ver se acho alguma forma de tirar o registro os registros filho.

Answer (score 1):

Olá Marlon pelo o que me parece quando você marca o objeto com state modified, o EF entende que todos os seus campos foram modificados, e já que existe um relacionamento entre os models, acaba gerando o erro. Eu acredito que definindo esse relacionamento como "cascade" pode resolver o problema, ou talvez você pode tentar fazer as alterações desta forma:

```
ProdutoPadrao.Campo1 = "Valor 1";
ProdutoPadrao.Campo2 = "Valor 2";
context.ListProdutoPadrao.Attach(ProdutoPadrao);
context.Entry(ProdutoPadrao).Property(p => p.Campo1).IsModified = true;
context.Entry(ProdutoPadrao).Property(p => p.Campo2).IsModified = true;
```

A forma que citei acima, não irá colocar o state "modified" em sua foreign-key, então o EF muito provavelmente não irá acusar o erro.

Obs.: Não sei o nome do seu DbSet no seu context, então dei o nome de "ListProdutoPadrao"